# React Native funnel chart

Tags: react-native, d3.js, react-native-ios, react-native-svg

Is there any React native package to create funnel chart like in this?

[image: need react-native package to implement]

or  how to implement this chart on our own in react-native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to drawing lines, shapes, gradients, etc, you have about two decent options in the react-native space.

The first one is [React Native Art](https://github.com/react-native-community/art), the second one is [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg). There are some charting libraries available as well, but when you want full customisation and styling/design options, the best way probably is to stay as close to the drawing api's as possible.

The funnel-graph-js project you mention uses browser SVG to draw the funnel chart, so I guess you can probably copy and adjust some code to achieve a similar result using react-native-svg.